# How to register new UDF in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

My Apache IoTDB server reported an error: `failed to reflect UDF instance because UDF VALUEFILL has not been registered`. I understand that it seems like I need to register this UDF before I use it in IoTDB, but I don't know how to register this new UDF. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of registering a UDF in Apache IoTDB is as follows:

1. Implement a complete UDF class.
2. Package your project into JAR.
3. Make preparations for registration according to the registration mode.
4. You can use this SQL to register UDF: `CREATE FUNCTION <UDF-NAME> AS <UDF-CLASS-FULL-PATHNAME> (USING URI URI-STRING)`.
   More detailed information can be checked in the official guide.